# How Quarkus @ApplicationScoped bean's injected dependency has different value every time

Tags: quarkus

I have below WebSocket bean class. I have injected JsonWebToken in this bean class and have a global property called clientIdGlobal. OnOpen I am picking clientId from token and assigning it to clientIdGlobal property.

```
package sample.sockettest;

import io.quarkus.security.Authenticated;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.websocket.*;
import jakarta.websocket.server.PathParam;
import jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken;

@ServerEndpoint(
        value = "/api/v1/samplesocket/"
)
@ApplicationScoped
@Authenticated
public class WebSocket {
    @Inject
    JsonWebToken jsonWebToken;

    String clientIdGlobal = "";

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        String clientId = jsonWebToken.getClaim("client_id");
        clientIdGlobal = clientId; // Picking clientId form token and assigning to clientIdGlobal property.
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) { 
        String clientId = jsonWebToken.getClaim("client_id");
        String x = clientIdGlobal; // last connected clientId always.
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) { 
        String clientId = jsonWebToken.getClaim("client_id");
        String x = clientIdGlobal; // last connected clientId always.
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) { 
        String clientId = jsonWebToken.getClaim("client_id");
        String x = clientIdGlobal; // last connected clientId always.
    }
}
```

Expectation:

1. There will be only one instance of WebSocket class.
2. clientIdGlobal - Behaves as expected because there is only one instance and the data, we change in global property will persist in subsequent injects (I would not be using this global variable, used just for testing).
3. jsonWebToken - **Here I see token came is exactly belonging to the respective client not just in OnOpen but also in OnMessage. How is this token dynamically changing? I would not be surprised if it is injected into method but here inject is in class level which should ideally happen once at object creation right.**

It would be great if someone explains how this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

As you are keeping request specific state in the `WebSocket` class (remember that `@JsonWebToken` is a `@RequestScoped` bean), you should make `WebSocket` `@RequestScoped` as well

Comment: Where is this mentioned? I checked this interface implementations. I did not see `RequestScoped` annotation.

@ApplicationScoped bean can have smaller scoped bean like @RequestScoped according to this questionary https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#client_proxies

Still I am not getting how this value is changed dynamically. Can you elaborate something like Application started -> Websocket class is initialized -> WebSocket connection established -> Session object is created and invoked Websocket class with session -> Message received -> Gets respective token form somewhere. (session instance?)

Comment: I am guessing that when WebSocket connection is established it quarkus will create session object and have token inside it because token can be passed only on connection request with upgrade for websockets as header info. So, I am guessing there is a listener in this session object which reads messages from websockets and then will invoke this Handler class we created based on ServerEndpoint annotation config. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I am not sure if I get exact info if I ask in github but git hub redirected me here for questions. So, hoping for a little deep answer for understanding the framework better.

Comment: It's quite simple actually: As you are using `@ApplicationScoped`, the instance is shared by all requests so when you add state to that instance (in the form of a field) that is based on properties of a request, you have absolutely no idea means of controlling which value is being used every time the field is accessed.